# How to display single column data in inside of @php in Laravel blade file

Tags: laravel-blade

I can display id data as this code.

```
{{ $image->id }}
```

however this below code didn't work.
Could you teach me how to write correct code in @php please?

```
@php
   if({{$image->id}} = "6"){
     echo "ID is six";
   }
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use variables without {{ }} inside @php
2. You need to use == for comparison
3. No need to add quotes to id.

try this

```
@php
   if($image->id == 6){
     echo "ID is six";
   }
@endphp
```